# Oracle Pro*C precompiler errors on EXEC SQL statements in included files

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

I'm converting some legacy code to Oracle Pro*C.  I'm on a Linux box using Oracle 11.2. We are using ".cp" as the suffix for Pro*C source files.  I'm not much of a C developer so I am sort of banging around in the dark as I go.

At one point I have some code in a shared library file, "assign_field.cp," so in myprog.cp I am doing

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE "assign_field.cp";
```

Now, in assign_field.cp, I have a very common line of Pro*C code...

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;
```

For this line, **along with many others**, I am seeing the following compiler output:

```
assign_field.cp:35: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âSQLâ
```

It looks as though the compiler isn't recognizing that this is Pro*C code.

I've got other include files that look very similar to assign_field.cp but which appear to compile just fine when included.

Comment: I don't understand your description of what you're doing. If `assign_field.cp` is a source file that makes up part of a shared library, why are you trying to include it in (what I assume is) your executable? Surely you should be linking to the library later? I would expect each `.cp` file to compile to its own `.o` file, and for those to be linked into libraries or executables as appropriate. If this is common, rather than really library code, then it might make sense, and require the `exec sql`. Not sure if I'm missing something - not a C expert either... Also, did you inherit a makefile?

Comment: I did inherit a makefile. (whoops, hit enter too soon) I don't have .h files for the .cp files that appear as though they need to be included, which is why I was just directly including the .cp files in the source file.

Comment: Does your makefile create a library and then link the exe to it; or create separate `.o`s for the `.cp`s and link several into the exe; or does it not mention `assign_field` at all? Still not quite sure... is `myprog.cp` calling functions that are in `assign_field.cp` but doesn't have (extern) declarations for them, which you expected to see in a related `.h`?

Comment: The makefile does not explicitly mention assign_field at all.  The makefile's activity is complicated by the presence of the Oracle Pro*C precompiler instructions. myprog.cp is calling functions that are in assign_field.cp and does not have extern declarations for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the C files (in this case, .cp files) in the program's flow.  Compile them separately; refer only to the function's declaration, such as in an included .h file. Refer to the compiled object files (probably .o) in the call to the linker in the makefile.